# @Html.RouteLink can not pass first route map

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make url as short as possible. In my base controller, I am setting some default values. And my routes are;

```
       routes.MapRoute(
          name: "SeoLink",
          url: "{SeoLink}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Default"}).DataTokens.Add("area", "Site");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "NewLanguage",
          url: "{NewLanguage}",
          defaults: new {controller = "Default", action = "Default"}).DataTokens.Add("area", "Site");
```

As you can see, they are same. When I use Html.RouteLink to check if its coming as NewLanguage url value in Base Controller, it does not bypass first SeoLink route. NewLanguage value comes like SeoLink value. Why?

```
@Html.RouteLink("English", "NewLanguage", new RouteValueDictionary(new { NewLanguage = "en" }),null)
```

I know there are better and correct ways. But just trying to understand how RouteLink work.

Comment: Routes are chosen in the order they are set up, not sure what you expected to happen here.

Comment: I want to use second route to be able to set language value in base controller like, if (filterContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("NewLanguage")) but it does not come with NewLanguage key instead SeoLink

Comment: But the second route does nothing different to the first one...

Comment: I try to check its value in Base Controller, (filterContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("NewLanguage")) by using Html.Routelink. But Html.RouteLink does not set Key name of RouteData.